# Android: pictures not showing in photo display Activity

Tags: java, android

EDIT: I figured out what what wrong, like I said I changed the package name to from `com.musicbynumbers.pianoscales` to `com.musicbynumbers.pianoscalesfull`. But I forgot to

`change int id =getResources().getIdentifier("com.musicbynumbers.pianoscalesfull:drawable/" + gotScale, null, null);`

All the code was good. Thanks a lot for your help.

Ok, this is just some beckground info before I get into the exact problem:
  I'm using eclipse. I published my first app a piano scales app on the play store a few weeks ago with licencing. Two days ago I realised that the licencing prevented some users who paid for the app from using it. I commented out the licencing and went to update but my keystore was corrupted. So I removed the app from the store and changed the package name. The app is a menu that brings you to a display Activity where the selected image is displayed. While I was testing the app again I found that only the default android image is displayed. I dont think I changed any of the code in the submenu or the display activities since it was working, But I'll put them up anyway. BTW this is my first app and the app is sechedualed to be released tomorrow accompanying a book, so this is some real 11th hour situation for me.

This is one of several submenu's that leads to the activity "display"

```
    package com.musicbynumbers.scales;



import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.PixelFormat;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.WindowManager;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ImageButton; 
import com.musicbynumbers.pianoscalesfull.R;

public class majorScales extends Activity implements View.OnClickListener  {
    Button aflatmaj, amaj, bflatmaj, bmaj, cmaj, dflatmaj, dmaj, eflatmaj, emaj, fmaj, fsharpmaj, gmaj;  
    ImageButton mainMenu;
    Intent j;
    String scaleName;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        getWindow().setFormat(PixelFormat.RGBA_8888);
        getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DITHER);
        setContentView(R.layout.majorscales);
        j  = new Intent(this, display.class);
        mainMenu = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.imagelogo);
        aflatmaj = (Button) findViewById(R.id.aflatmajb);
        amaj = (Button) findViewById(R.id.amajb);
        bflatmaj = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bflatmajb);
        bmaj = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bmajb);
        cmaj = (Button) findViewById(R.id.cmajb);
        dflatmaj = (Button) findViewById(R.id.dflatmajb);
        dmaj = (Button) findViewById(R.id.dmajb);
        eflatmaj = (Button) findViewById(R.id.eflatmajb);
        emaj = (Button) findViewById(R.id.emajb);
        fmaj = (Button) findViewById(R.id.fmajb);
        fsharpmaj = (Button) findViewById(R.id.fsharpmajb);
        gmaj = (Button) findViewById(R.id.gmajb);
        mainMenu.setOnClickListener(this);
        aflatmaj.setOnClickListener(this);
        amaj.setOnClickListener(this);
        bflatmaj.setOnClickListener(this);
        bmaj.setOnClickListener(this);
        cmaj.setOnClickListener(this);
        dflatmaj.setOnClickListener(this);
        dmaj.setOnClickListener(this);
        eflatmaj.setOnClickListener(this);
        emaj.setOnClickListener(this);
        fmaj.setOnClickListener(this);
        fsharpmaj.setOnClickListener(this);
        gmaj.setOnClickListener(this);



    }






         @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                switch(arg0.getId()){
                case R.id.imagelogo:
                    Intent i =  new Intent(majorScales.this, MainMenu.class);
                    startActivity(i);
                    break;
                case R.id.aflatmajb:
                    scaleName = "aflatmaj";
                    j.putExtra("key", scaleName);

                    startActivity(j);
                    break;
                case R.id.amajb:
                    scaleName = "amaj";
                    j.putExtra("key", scaleName);
                    startActivity(j);
                    break;
                case R.id.bflatmajb:
                    scaleName = "bflatmaj";
                    j.putExtra("key", scaleName);
                    startActivity(j);
                    break;
                case R.id.bmajb:
                    scaleName = "bmaj";
                    j.putExtra("key", scaleName);
                    startActivity(j);
                    break;
                case R.id.cmajb:
                    scaleName = "cmaj";
                    j.putExtra("key", scaleName);
                    startActivity(j);
                    break;
                case R.id.dflatmajb:
                    scaleName = "dflatmaj";
                    j.putExtra("key", scaleName);
                    startActivity(j);
                    break;
                case R.id.dmajb:
                    scaleName = "dmaj";
                    j.putExtra("key", scaleName);
                    startActivity(j);
                    break;
                case R.id.eflatmajb:
                    scaleName = "eflatmaj";
                    j.putExtra("key", scaleName);
                    startActivity(j);
                    break;
                case R.id.emajb:
                    scaleName = "emaj";
                    j.putExtra("key", scaleName);
                    startActivity(j);
                    break;
                case R.id.fmajb:
                    scaleName = "fmaj";
                    j.putExtra("key", scaleName);
                    startActivity(j);
                    break;
                case R.id.fsharpmajb:
                    scaleName = "fsharpmaj";
                    j.putExtra("key", scaleName);
                    startActivity(j);
                    break;
                case R.id.gmajb:
                    scaleName = "gmaj";
                    j.putExtra("key", scaleName);
                    startActivity(j);
                    break;




    }

}
}
```

This is the display activity where the selected image is displayed but only the default is being displayed now.

```
package com.musicbynumbers.scales;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import com.musicbynumbers.pianoscalesfull.R;


public class display extends Activity {

    ImageView displayScale;
    String gotScale;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.display);
        Initalize();
        gotScale = getIntent().getStringExtra("key");
        ImageView displayScale = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.displayImage);
        //aflatmaj-gotscale
        int id = getResources().getIdentifier("com.musicbynumbers.pianoscales:drawable/" + gotScale, null, null);
        displayScale.setImageResource(id);

    }

    private void Initalize() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        displayScale = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.displayImage);
        gotScale = "ic_launcher.png";

    }}
```

I really appreciate any help because I'm running out of time.

Edit:

Logcat:

```
03-11 18:38:00.194: I/ActivityManager(59): Starting activity: Intent { cmp=com.musicbynumbers.pianoscalesfull/com.musicbynumbers.scales.majorScales }
03-11 18:38:00.824: W/ActivityManager(59): Activity pause timeout for HistoryRecord{45f03618 com.musicbynumbers.pianoscalesfull/com.musicbynumbers.scales.MainMenu}
03-11 18:38:03.284: I/ActivityManager(59): Displayed activity com.musicbynumbers.pianoscalesfull/com.musicbynumbers.scales.majorScales: 2454 ms (total 2454 ms)
03-11 18:38:07.854: I/ActivityManager(59): Starting activity: Intent { cmp=com.musicbynumbers.pianoscalesfull/com.musicbynumbers.scales.display (has extras) }
03-11 18:38:08.234: I/WindowManager(59): Setting rotation to 1, animFlags=1
03-11 18:38:08.404: I/ActivityManager(59): Config changed: { scale=1.0 imsi=310/260 loc=en_US touch=3 keys=2/1/2 nav=3/1 orien=2 layout=18 uiMode=17 seq=32}
03-11 18:38:09.616: I/ActivityManager(59): Displayed activity com.musicbynumbers.pianoscalesfull/com.musicbynumbers.scales.display: 1384 ms (total 1384 ms)
03-11 18:38:13.123: D/dalvikvm(59): GC_EXPLICIT freed 3329 objects / 183760 bytes in 462ms
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't get it:

In the display activity you have: `ImageView displayScale;` declared at the beginning and then you declare it again: `ImageView displayScale = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.displayImage);`

And this a problem mainly among other reason becaouse you got the Initalize(); going on there.

if you are saying that you are not reciving anything but the default android image then clearly

```
gotScale = getIntent().getStringExtra("key");
```

not working and all what's left is the: `gotScale = "ic_launcher.png";` from the initialization.

Try to log the `gotScale` parameter right before you get the image depending on it to see what it holds.

**EDIT:**

To log:

Log.d("ActivityName", "The message you want to show");

and monitor your logcat using the cmd to see the log message.

or you can always show a toast to see what is the content of `gotScale`.

Comment: I see that, Iv'e changed the second one in the oncreate to     displayScale = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.displayImage); and im testing it on the emulator

Comment: "Try to log the gotScale parameter right before you get the image depending on it to see what it holds." How would I do that? Sorry Im quite new.

Comment: When I did it it gave "amaj" after clicking amajb so the right data is getting to gotData.

Comment: I figured out what what wrong, like I said I changed the package name to from com.musicbynumbers.pianoscales to  com.musicbynumbers.pianoscalesfull. But I forgot to change             int id = getResources().getIdentifier("com.musicbynumbers.pianoscalesfull:drawable/" + gotScale, null, null);   All the code was good. Thanks a lot for your help.

Answer (score 0):

I have not tested the code from my side. So you can take it as a suggestion. After inspecting your code it seems

```
int id = getResources().getIdentifier("com.musicbynumbers.pianoscales:drawable/" + gotScale, null, null);
        displayScale.setImageResource(id);
```

looks odd. Can you log the identifier returned and verify it.

// A good replacement you can even try.
//get icons

```
     String uri = "drawable/"+gotScale;
int id = getResources().getIdentifier(uri, "drawable", getPackageName()); // your res id.
```

Hope this will help you to save some time. :)

Comment: does anything need to go in "drawable" or is it just left like that. That might seem quite obvious but I'm relatively new. And logging the identifier do you mean copy that section of the log cat?

Comment: does anything need to go in "drawable" or is it just left like that. That might seem quite obvious but I'm relatively new. And logging the identifier do you mean copy that section of the log cat?

Comment: I added the logcat to the main question

Comment: I figured out what what wrong, like I said I changed the package name to from com.musicbynumbers.pianoscales to com.musicbynumbers.pianoscalesfull. But I forgot to change int id = getResources().getIdentifier("com.musicbynumbers.pianoscalesfull:drawable/" + gotScale, null, null); All the code was good. Thanks a lot for your help.

Comment: glad to know that you got the solution. Anyways, here logging means check your ids in logs and match if it calls the required id's or not. You would have got where the problem lies much earlier. Cheers!